TIP120 excessive voltage drop
I've been trying to make my own H-bridge using a TIP120.  With the test circuit below, I was expecting to get ~6V at minimum across the resistor but I'm getting less than 3V.
The circuit still outputs less than 3V even with a base resistor. I've figured giving 5V at the base yields greater voltage, but I really need to operate it with 3.3V. I have checked and reassembled the circuit numerous times, so I'm a bit clueless on this one. Can anyone help? (I'm a bit of a noob with Darlingtons.)


The schematic shows 8.943 V across R1. Seems unlikely. On the other hand, you write that there is less than 3 V across R1. That is much more likely. Where did the 8.943 V come from?

hi, sorry for the confusion! the 8.943V was given by the schematic CAD, I could not control it. The resistor I talked about is not shown, as I did not see it to have any effect. @MathKeepsMeBusy

Tip: when you use the editor toolbar CircuitLab button to draw your schematic you can use the Save and Insert button to insert a PNG of the schematic into the post along with an edit link. There's no need for a CircuitLab account. No screengrab. No grid. It also means that others can copy and paste your schematic for further editing.

The problem has nothing to do with the fact that you are using a Darlington transistor.
The problem lies in that you are using the transistor in a common collector configuration.  The voltage at the emitter of the transistor can never be higher than the voltage at the base.  To get 9V at the emitter, you must apply 9V to the base plus the base voltage drop - total of about 10.4V.

The problem is certainly exacerbated by using a Darlington -- it'll drop around 1.4V base to emitter, instead of 0.7V if it weren't a Darlington.

"To get 9V at the emitter you must apply 9V at the base".  No -- to get 9V at the emitter you need to apply at least 10.4V at the base, possibly more.

Thank you for the tip! As they will be used on a H-Bridge, mind sharing how such configuration could be implemented for the full H-bridge?
